# Custom model binder not retrieving value from value-provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a Custom model binder that will convert posted values to another model.
Issue is `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName)` returns none even if there are values posted from client.

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, 
                           [Bind(Prefix = "models")] AnotherModel items)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

**Target Model Class**

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyModelBinder))]
public class AnotherModel
{
    IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Cutomer Model Binder**

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        // ISSUE: valueProviderResult is always None
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }


        //here i will convert valueProviderResult to AnotherModel


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Quick watch shows ValueProvider does have values

[image]

**UPDATE1**

Inside the Update action method when i can iterate through IFormCollection, The Request.Form has all the Key and Value pair. Not sure why model binder is not able to retrieve it.

```
foreach (var f in HttpContext.Request.Form)
{
    var key = f.Key;
    var v = f.Value;
}
```

Comment: Hint from mvc's collection binder; https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/CollectionModelBinder.cs#L136

Comment: Could you share your post data?Also,you receive `AnotherModel` instead of `List<AnotherModel >` but you pass the data like `models[0].property`.You need to pass `models.property1`,`models.property2`...And what is your `DataSourceRequest`?Did it impact your result if you delete it?

Comment: @Rena Its a POST from Kendo grid.  Here is the captured POST from fiddler `sort=&group=&filter=&models%5B0%5D.Id=2&models%5B0%5D.FirstName=foo&models%5B0%5D.LastName=bar`

Answer (score 1):

> My example

In my client I send a header in request, this header is Base64String(Json Serialized object)

Object -> Json -> Base64.

Headers can't be multiline. With base64 we get 1 line.

All of this are applicable to Body and other sources.

**Header class**

```
public class RequestHeader : IHeader
{
    [Required]
    public PlatformType Platform { get; set; } //Windows / Android / Linux / MacOS / iOS

    [Required]
    public ApplicationType ApplicationType { get; set; } 

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string UserAgent { get; set; } = null!; 

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string ClientName { get; set; } = null!; 

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Token { get; set; } = null!; 


    public string ToSerializedString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

**IHeader Interface**

```
public interface IHeader
{
}
```

**Model Binder**

```
public class HeaderParameterModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        StringValues headerValue = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Where(h =>
        {
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            return h.Key.Equals(bindingContext.ModelName ?? guid) | 
                   h.Key.Equals(bindingContext.ModelType.Name ?? guid) | 
                   h.Key.Equals(bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ParameterName); 
        }).Select(h => h.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if (headerValue.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                //Convert started
                bindingContext.Model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(headerValue)), bindingContext.ModelType);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.Model);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Model Binder Provider**

We can work with any BindingSource.

- Body
- BindingSource Custom
- BindingSource Form
- BindingSource FormFile
- BindingSource Header
- BindingSource ModelBinding
- BindingSource Path
- BindingSource Query
- BindingSource Services
- BindingSource Special

```
public class ParametersModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public ParametersModelBinderProvider(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType.GetInterfaces().Where(value => value.Name.Equals(nameof(ISecurityParameter))).Any() && BindingSource.Header.Equals(context.Metadata.BindingSource))
        {
            return new SecurityParameterModelBinder(configuration);
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType.GetInterfaces().Where(value=>value.Name.Equals(nameof(IHeader))).Any() && BindingSource.Header.Equals(context.Metadata.BindingSource))
        {
            return new HeaderParameterModelBinder();
        }
        return null!;
    }
}
```

**In Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0,new ParametersModelBinderProvider(configuration));
    });
}
```

**Controller action**

ExchangeResult is my result class.

```
[HttpGet(nameof(Exchange))]
public ActionResult<ExchangeResult> Exchange([FromHeader(Name = nameof(RequestHeader))] RequestHeader header)
{
    //RequestHeader previously was processed in modelbinder.
    //RequestHeader is null or object instance.  
    //Some instructions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the source code of MVC's [CollectionModelBinder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/CollectionModelBinder.cs#L154), you'd notice that values of the form "name[index]" will return ValueProviderResult.None and need to be handled separately.

It seems like you're trying to solve the wrong problem. I'd suggest binding to a standard collection class like `Dictionary`.

Either;

```cs
public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, 
                           [Bind(Prefix = "models")] Dictionary<string, RecordTypeName> items)
```

Or;

```cs
public class AnotherModel : Dictionary<string, RecordTypeName> {}
```

If you don't know what type each dictionary value will have at compile time, that's where a custom binder would come in handy.

Comment: i tried Dictionary<string,object> but it did not work. Note that the `items` argument is a collection of grid rows. So it must be `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>>` Where each `Dictionary<string,object>` represent a single row

Comment: So you want to bind `List<Dictionary<string,object>>`?  You're posting `models[0].Id = `, so a `List<T>` with a `T.Id` field would also work.

Comment: Columns of the grid are dynamic..i dont know the 'T' at design time